# How to change the properties of a lottie animation using the lottie for flutter package?

Tags: flutter, animation

I am unable to change the properties of a lottie animation I have set up in flutter. (I specifically wish to change the color.)

Based on the package README I understand I can use a ValueDelegate class to do this.

[README](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)

```
//From the README

    return Lottie.asset(
      'assets/Tests/Shapes.json',
      delegates: LottieDelegates(
        text: (initialText) => '**$initialText**',
        values: [
          ValueDelegate.color(
            const ['Shape Layer 1', 'Rectangle', 'Fill 1'],'
// UNSURE WHERE TO OBTAIN THESE ABOVE PROPERTY VALUES //
            value: Colors.red,
          ),
```

```
\\here is my code - I am unsure how to obtain the appropriate values for keyPath, value and callBack properties, in the ValueDelegate.color.

                  child: Lottie.asset(
                    'assets/lottie/audio.json',
                    delegates: LottieDelegates(
                      text: (initialText) => '**$initialText**',
                      values: [
                        ValueDelegate.color(
                          const ['Path 1','ADBE Vector Shape - Group','Fill 1'],
                          value: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

~~~


This is the JSON file of the lottie animation I am currently working with....

{"v":"5.1.18","fr":29.9700012207031,"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"w":20,"h":20,"nm":"Comp 1","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"wave_2 Outlines","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.916},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.085},"n":"0p833_0p916_0p167_0p085","t":0,"s":[18.118,9.963,0],"e":[16.868,9.963,0],"to":[-0.20833332836628,0,0],"ti":[0.20833332836628,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.167,"y":0.167},"n":"0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167","t":8,"s":[16.868,9.963,0],"e":[16.868,9.963,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.623,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.194,"y":0.147},"n":"0p623_1_0p194_0p147","t":13,"s":[16.868,9.963,0],"e":[18.118,9.963,0],"to":[0.20833332836628,0,0],"ti":[-0.20833332836628,0,0]},{"t":25.0000010182709}],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[2.827,7.401,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0.192,0],[0.146,0.147],[-0.293,0.293],[3.217,3.217],[-0.293,0.293],[-0.293,-0.293],[3.801,-3.801]],"o":[[-0.192,0],[-0.293,-0.293],[3.217,-3.217],[-0.293,-0.293],[0.293,-0.293],[3.801,3.802],[-0.146,0.147]],"v":[[-1.406,7.151],[-1.936,6.931],[-1.936,5.871],[-1.936,-5.797],[-1.936,-6.858],[-0.876,-6.858],[-0.876,6.931]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"mm","mm":4,"nm":"Merge Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Merge","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.6,0.6,0.647000002394,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[2.479,7.401],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"wave_1 Outlines","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.89},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0.23},"n":"0p833_0p89_0p333_0p23","t":4,"s":[14.063,9.959,0],"e":[13.125,9.959,0],"to":[-0.15625,0,0],"ti":[0.15625,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.667,"y":0.667},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0.333},"n":"0p667_0p667_0p333_0p333","t":13,"s":[13.125,9.959,0],"e":[13.125,9.959,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.711,"y":0.995},"o":{"x":0.102,"y":0.082},"n":"0p711_0p995_0p102_0p082","t":19,"s":[13.125,9.959,0],"e":[14.063,9.959,0],"to":[0.15625,0,0],"ti":[-0.15625,0,0]},{"t":30.0000012219251}],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[1.95,4.218,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0.192,0],[0.146,0.147],[-0.293,0.293],[1.462,1.462],[-0.293,0.293],[-0.293,-0.292],[2.046,-2.048]],"o":[[-0.191,0],[-0.293,-0.292],[1.462,-1.462],[-0.293,-0.293],[0.293,-0.292],[2.046,2.047],[-0.146,0.147]],"v":[[-0.876,3.969],[-1.406,3.749],[-1.406,2.689],[-1.406,-2.615],[-1.406,-3.676],[-0.346,-3.676],[-0.346,3.749]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.6,0.6,0.647000002394,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[1.95,4.218],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":2,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":5,"ty":4,"nm":"speaker Outlines","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[5.049,9.975,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[5.051,7.326,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[-0.132,-0.106],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0.17,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0.17,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-0.132,0.106],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-3.301,1.976],[-0.45,1.976],[0.018,2.14],[3.301,4.765],[3.301,-4.716],[0.018,-2.09],[-0.45,-1.926],[-3.301,-1.926]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ind":1,"ty":"sh","ix":2,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0.11,0],[0.136,0.109],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0.414],[0,0],[-0.414,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-0.26,-0.124],[0,-0.289],[0,0],[0.26,-0.124]],"o":[[-0.167,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-0.414,0],[0,0],[0,-0.414],[0,0],[0,0],[0.225,-0.181],[0.26,0.124],[0,0],[0,0.289],[-0.104,0.051]],"v":[[4.051,7.076],[3.582,6.912],[-0.713,3.476],[-4.051,3.476],[-4.801,2.726],[-4.801,-2.676],[-4.051,-3.426],[-0.713,-3.426],[3.582,-6.862],[4.376,-6.952],[4.801,-6.276],[4.801,6.326],[4.376,7.001]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 2","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"mm","mm":1,"nm":"Merge Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Merge","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.6,0.6,0.647000002394,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[5.051,7.326],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":4,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

Comment: Does anyone knows how i can change the asset image data

{
      "id": "image_0",
      "w": 32,
      "h": 32,
      "u": "",
      "p": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORwCC",
      "e": 1
    }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ValueDelegate.color` goes through the Lottie file in hierarchical order and selects the colors to change as specified in the `keyPath` list. This order is labeled in the code below as *layer*, *group* and *shape name*.

For example, if you wish to select all the groups with name `wave_2 Outlines`, all the layers should also be selected by using '**' for the layer name in the key path.

```
delegates: LottieDelegates(
  values: [
    ValueDelegate.color(
      // keyPath order: ['layer name', 'group name', 'shape name']
      const ['**', 'wave_2 Outlines', '**'],
      value: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ],
),
```

This approach also works to color several groups at once, provided they have the same group name in the Lottie file.

Comment: Any idea how i can change the asset of lottie json

Answer (score 5):

I use ColorFiltered for some cases.

```
 ColorFiltered(
                      colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
                        Colors.red,
                        BlendMode.modulate,
                      ),
                      child: Lottie.asset(
                        "assets/lottie/delete.json",
                        controller: _animationControllerDelete,
```

Answer (score 1):

*Value* and *ValueCallback* get called every time the animation is rendered.

So there are no values to obtain. You have to define the changes you want to effect, such as changing the colour. But keep in mind that you can only use one of them, using both results in an exception being thrown.

The value for *keyPath* can be obtained from your Lottie JSON file. The keyPath is the nm value for each of the image's layers.

So referring to your JSON file. At the very top level of each layer, there are three keyPath values you can use:

- wave_2_outlines
- wave_1_outlines
- speaker Outlines

I use this VS Code [JSON extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZainChen.json) to analyse my files, making it much easier to find the values.

```
{
   "v":"5.1.18",
   "fr":29.9700012207031,
   "ip":0,
   "op":60.0000024438501,
   "w":20,
   "h":20,
   "nm":"Comp 1",
   "ddd":0,
   "assets":[
      
   ],
   "layers":[
      {
         "ddd":0,
         "ind":1,
         "ty":4,
         "nm":"wave_2 Outlines",
         ...
      },
      {
         "ddd":0,
         "ind":2,
         "ty":4,
         "nm":"wave_1 Outlines",
         ...
      },
      {
         "ddd":0,
         "ind":5,
         "ty":4,
         "nm":"speaker Outlines",
         ....
      }
   ]...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find how to change color using `ValueDelegate.color`
So i used `ValueDelegate.colorFilter` instead:

```
delegates: LottieDelegates(
   values: [
      ValueDelegate.colorFilter(
         ['wave_2 Outlines', '**'],
         value: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.src),
      ),
   ],
),
```

If you find a way using `ValueDelegate.color`, please post it here. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

For Lottie.asset I used this code (the change is "BlendMode.scrATop"):

```
        SizedBox(
          height: 60.0,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: ColorFiltered(
              colorFilter:
                  ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.srcATop),
              child: Lottie.asset(Lordicon.$12_arrow_down_outline,
                  controller: _animatedIconController),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // Blablabla
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code  for my file:

```
 Lottie.asset( 'assets/timerCyrcle.json',
        width: lottieSize,
        height: lottieSize, 
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        controller: _lottieController,
        repeat: false, 
        delegates: LottieDelegates(
          values: [
            ValueDelegate.colorFilter(
              ['inerCyrcle', '**'],
              value: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.src),
            ),
            ValueDelegate.colorFilter(
              ['outerCircle', '**'],
              value: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.src),
            ),
          ],
        ),`
```

Layer 1 - "inerCyrcle"
Name: "inerCyrcle"
Type: Shape layer ("ty": 4)
Keyframes ("ks") contain information about the ellipse's path, trim paths, stroke, and transform properties.

Layer 2 - "outerCircle"
Name: "outerCircle"
Type: Shape layer ("ty": 4)
Keyframes ("ks") contain information about the ellipse's path, stroke, trim paths, and transform properties.